# How can I use raycasthit according to the mouse cursor position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public Camera mapCamera;

private Camera[] cameras;
private GameObject mouseOvered;

void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            if (mapCamera.enabled == false)
            {
                foreach (Camera cam in cameras)
                {
                    cam.enabled = false;
                }
                mapCamera.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Camera cam in cameras)
                {
                    cam.enabled = true;
                }
                mapCamera.enabled = false;
            }
        }

        bool rcHit = false;
        Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;
        Ray castPoint = mapCamera.ScreenPointToRay(mouse);
        RaycastHit hit;
        Debug.DrawRay(mapCamera.transform.position, 
        mapCamera.transform.forward * Mathf.Infinity, Color.magenta);
        if (Physics.Raycast(castPoint, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            rcHit = true;
        if (mouseOvered != hit.collider.gameObject)
        {
            mouseOvered = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
        print(mouseOvered.name);
        //do your thing here to apply/change the material
    }
    if (!rcHit && mouseOvered != null)
    {
        //do your thing to undo the material change
        mouseOvered = null;
    }
   }
```

The problem is when I'm running the game I see the raycast laser still if I change in the Debug.DrawRay form Mathf.Infinity to 1000  and it's not moving according to the mouse cursor position. I'm moving the mouse cursor around but the raycast laser seems to stay at the same place so I guess It's hitting only specific places/objects and not everything ? Not sure what is going on.

If I'm using Mathf.Infinity I don't see the laser of the raycast at all.
And when I'm moving the mouse cursor around the space station only once it's detecting object and print it's name.

What I want to do is when I'm moving the mouse cursor around when it's hitting any object of the space station print it's name.

Only if I change on this line to 1000 for example then I see the magenta color:

```
Debug.DrawRay(mapCamera.transform.position, mapCamera.transform.forward * 1000, Color.magenta);
```

If it's Mathf.Infinity I don't see any magenta of the laser.

[image: Mag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the raycasting itself, the problem solely lies with what you draw. You dont draw *the* Ray, but *a* "Ray" from the camera position along its forward vector.

Replace

```
Debug.DrawRay(mapCamera.transform.position, mapCamera.transform.forward * Mathf.Infinity, Color.magenta);
```

With

```
Debug.DrawRay(castPoint.origin, castPoint.direction * Matf.Infinity, Color.magenta);
```

Tough im not sure if multiplying with infinity will work. Something like 1000 units (maybe even use `mapCamera.farClipPlane` as its unlikely a player wants to pick something outside it anyway) should be (more than) sufficient for most scenarios.

Comment: I changed the Debug line now the Ray is moving with the mouse.I also changed in both places from Mathf.Infinity to 1000. But it seems that it's not accurate. I mean I'm moving the mouse cursor around but I see that the Ray magenta laser is not where the mouse cursor is and it's not hitting all the time the right object/s on the space station. I need to move the mouse cursor a lot to get it hit.

Comment: Well the code for raycasting looks perfectly fine to me. Maybe try to move some GameObject to hit.point for debug reasons? You know, like some Cube or Sphere or smthg?!

Comment: the oddities you experience might be connected to the check you do "in" the raycast. if it hits you set mouseOvered if its different from the current hit.collider.GameObject, but if it doesnt hit you never unset it.

Comment: In the check I'm doing: if (!rcHit && mouseOvered != null) and inside I'm setting mouseOvered to null. What should I set it to ?

Comment: Right, sry I missed that as I was looking for an else block to the `if(Physics.Raycast(...))`. Did you find out something else?

Comment: I didn't find any solution why it's only sometimes detecting objects.  I will have to make a new complete project and check it on new clean project with one/two objects and a camera to see if it will work.

Comment: Ok I created a new project and it's working perfect there. So i figured out what was the problem. It's not a problem it was working perfect also in my first project. It's just I used print to display the result and i was watching the console at the bottom and it didn't change the printed name and since I didn't open the console window I didn't see it. So i added a canvas and a Text ui and now it's showing the names on the Text without a problem. All I can say is sorry for all the mess and troubles I did for you. It was working all this time I just didn't watch and show it right.